# IOS swift 3 crash for UITextFields editing and responder

Tags: ios, swift3, keyboard, uitextfield, first-responder

I'm facing a strange problem with dealing with `UITextField`s and `keyboard` visibility.

The purpose of my current controller is to let user edit some datas but also read some others.

So I decided to include few textfields in it and when user modify some data a button appears and he can press it to send modifications. But to read other datas `keyboard` has to hide.

I made some researches to find a working way to do so like :

- `self.view.endEditing(true)`
- `currentTextField.resignFirstResponder()`
- even create an "hidden UITextField" and ask it to `becomeFirstResponder` when process is done

None of these tries ended with a hide of the keyboard but ended with `Optional value` crash

I'm using `Swift 3` and `XCode 8.2.1` right now

If someone has a clue, thanks by advance

Comment: can you show some code.

Comment: Please enter some code. Have you used optional binding to avoid these kinds of crash?

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller needs to subclass UITextFieldDelegate. Implement the functions that are defined by this protocol and you should have the control you need. And don't forget to set `myTextfield.delegate = self` -- or whatever object implements the protocol.

An example would be "DidEndEditing" and similar. 
If you already did this please provide some code for further diagnosing your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers,

I implemented UITextFieldDelegate from begin of code and all my `TextField`s use `editingDidBegin` and `editingDidEnd` and crash occured when I called the code below from the result of an API Call

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

I just found a way to succeed the hide of keyboard using this code before the API call. The sad side is that this new way avoid the possibility to keep keyboard visible if the call fails.

Answer (score 0):

**self.view.endEditing(true)**

This line should not crash. It just resign responder from UITextfield. Can you please give me detail about your crash? What is written in log console when crash happens. as far as I know **self.view.endEditing(true)** will definitely fulfil your requirements.